# Can the contents of a script tag be cut off if it's too long?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I view the source of a certain webpage, there is a script tag that seems to be cut off at the end, ending with an ellipsis (...).  Is there a way to tell if the script is actually being cut off or if the ellipsis is actually part of the content?  If it is cut off, is there a way to view the whole thing?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it appears that Chrome Developer tool truncates the display of the content and shows an ellipses instead. The content is still there and parsed by the browser.

You can view the full content by going to the Sources tab, clicking on the Show Navigator icon, and selecting your file.

Comment: My script is being generated dynamically so it won't be available in the files section.
This is absolutely ridiculous!
I should at least be able to expand it or even when I click on Edit HTML it should give me the full content! Instead I'm editing cutoff script and the ellipses symbol!!! How did nobody at google think that this would be important??
I can't do anything to my code at runtime as dev now!

Comment: Switch to Firefox when you have dynamically created script tags, they are not truncated there.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers do not work if js code added dynamically. For me works when I do right click on script element and choose Copy -> Copy element

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

For those looking just to view or copy a cut off script tag, the solution I found to work for me is saving the web page to disk and then opening using a code editor. Obviously this won't allow you to edit in place or debug, but for copying it works great!

Answer (score 0):

If your truncated script is being generated dynamically, you will note that the truncated code is automatically highlighted/selected. If you copy this and paste it into a text editor, you will find that the complete/un-truncated section of script will be pasted. Not ideal, but not too much hassle either.